# Safari 13.04 CORS or CSP errors

Tags: safari, catalina

Recently Safari stopped opening sites and generates CORS issues.  I can no longer sign in with my Google account to various sites and I get the following errors when visiting a specific site:

> [Error] Blocked a frame with origin "https://site.example.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://digital.site.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
>
> [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.site.com/resources/fedb9a53ddb6 due to access control checks.
>       apicall_bm (f2a38f1554229420bddedb9a53ddb6:1:50052)
>       pd (f2a38f1554229420bddedb9a53ddb6:1:50314)
>       calc_fp (f2a38f1554229420bddedb9a53ddb6:1:55113)

Things I have tried:

- Turned on developer more and emptied caches as well as deleted everything in the /Users/user/Library/Safari Folder
- Cleared all history
- Disable Cross Origin Restrictions (It now gets passed first error but still throws another)

Google Chrome and Firefox work just fine.

Specs: macOS Catalina and Safari 13.04